# Dynamic Graphic Image

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to have dynamic graphic image from database.
I found a few according questions here in SO but somehow it does not work.

Page:

```
<p:dataList styleClass="routeDatalist" value="#{searchRoutesBean.foundRoutes}" var="uiRoute">
    <p:outputLabel value="USERID #{uiRoute.owner.id}"/>
    <h:graphicImage value="#{photoStreamer.streamedContent}" styleClass="userProfileImage">
    <f:param name="userId" value="#{uiRoute.owner.id}" />
    </h:graphicImage>
<p:/dataList>
```

I get my list of objects from backing bean

```
    @SessionScoped
    @ManagedBean
    public class SearchRoutesBean{
     private List<UIRoute> foundRoutes;
      ...
    }
```

I created a backing bean which should take the userimage bytearray and create a streamed content

```
 @ManagedBean(name = "photoStreamer")
@ApplicationScoped
public class PhotoStreamer implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    private StreamedContent streamedContent;

    public StreamedContent getStreamedContent() {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext();
    String userId = externalContext.getRequestParameterMap().get("userId");

    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userId)) {

        User user;
        try {
        user = userService.getUserById(Long.valueOf(userId));
        byte[] image = user.getProfileJpegImage();
        if (image != null && image.length > 0) {
            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                image), "image/jpeg");
        } else {
            BufferedImage bufferedImg = new BufferedImage(250, 350,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImg.createGraphics();
            g2.drawString("User has no ProfilImage", 50, 175);
            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            ImageIO.write(bufferedImg, "png", os);

            return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(
                os.toByteArray()), "image/png");
        }
        } catch (NumberFormatException | UserServiceException | IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }

    }
    return null;

    }
}
```

I dont know why but the given parameter userId is always null.

Does someone know what could be the problem?
BR

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imiBwk_xqaE

Comment: This is excactly what I am doing?! The only difference is that i am using a dataList instead of dataTable.

Comment: try with datatable and see if that works for you first.

Comment: Well as you can see it works in my example. Download the example and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
<p:dataList styleClass="routeDatalist" value="#{searchRoutesBean.foundRoutes}" var="uiRoute">
    <p:outputLabel value="USERID #{uiRoute.owner.id}"/>
    <h:graphicImage value="#{photoStreamer.streamedContent(uiRoute.owner.id)}" styleClass="userProfileImage"/>
<p:/dataList>
```

+

```
public StreamedContent getStreamedContent(String userId) {

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(userId)) {

        User user;
        try {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: This is what i also tried but I found the problem ty :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that dataList need to be wrapped into h:form.
Thx to Makky who send me this tutorial
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imiBwk_xqaE